# How to not accept upper case letters as input? While also making the person re-enter thier username until its all lowercase

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the code to stop the person and say "hey its gotta be all lowercase"
And then make them input it again until its all lowercase. I was trying something like this:

```
username=input("Enter username ")
while username[::] .upper():
    print("username cannot have capital letters")
    username = input("Enter username ")
```

Comment: I think your question title is incorrect. I believe it should be "How to not accept **upper** case letters as input?"

Comment: ``
    import re
    username_re = re.compile(r"^[0-9]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$")
    username=input("Enter username ")
    
    m = username_re.match(username)
    while not m:
        username=input("Enter username ")
        print("username cannot have capital letters")
        m = username_re.match(username)
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`string.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower) for this:

```
username=input("Enter username ")
while not username.islower():
    print("username cannot have capital letters")
    username = input("Enter username ")
```

If you want to allow, for example, `username = "@123"`, you could instead use

```
import string

username=input("Enter username ")
while any(c in string.ascii_uppercase for c in username):
    print("username cannot have capital letters")
    username = input("Enter username ")
```

Comment: @CDJB i think its easier to just do `username == username.lower()` for your second example. `"@123".lower() == "@123"` evaluates to True

Comment: @GrantWilliams also a valid option

Comment: No this is perfect because I don't want to change there username because then people will think its capital when its not. thank you both so much for your help!